# How to execute a non blocking C# method at regular intervals?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# Class. I need to execute its instance at regular intervals say 5 minutes. I need to execute this code every 5 minutes without blocking the main thread. Also I would like to have a mechanism where I can stop this process.

Comment: You don't execute (instances of) a class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class.

Comment: There are 3 different timer classes (each in a different namespace). Depending on what you plan to do, you may prefer one over the others. This article is a little dated, but the information is still relevant. It might provide some insight on your design decisions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx